# Change Input cells to TraditionalForm on Shift+Enter?

Tags: formatting

In version 11.1 the use of TraditionalForm as a Preference option has been deleted.

Changing the CommonDefaultFormatTypes in  Options: Cell Options section from StandardForm to TraditionalForm for both Input and Output does not result in a TraditionalForm for the Input cell. You still need to right click and Convert the Input Cell or //TraditionalForm.

Is there a way to have the Input convert to TraditionalForm automatically on hitting the enter key?

Comment: Wolfram has documented the items removed from the preferences menu [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/28318), for what it's worth. It looks like most of them got moved to the option inspector, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Option Inspector works for me. Alternatively, you could use:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Input" -> TraditionalForm}]
```

Then, new notebooks will use `TraditionalForm`.

As far as I know, Mathematica never converted input cells to [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) upon using Shift-Enter. If you do want to have the cell converted to [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) automatically after using Shift-Enter, you can do this with a stylesheet. For example, the following cell expression in a stylesheet should do what you want :

```
Cell[StyleData["Input"],
    CellEpilog :> With[{obj = EvaluationCell[]},
        SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, CellContents];
        FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionConvert", "TraditionalForm"]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but when you say "it works for me" are you referring to changing the values of CommonDefaultFormatTypes from StandardForm to InputForm for both input and output. When I do this the output does change to TraditionalForm but only the font changes for the Input. D[x^2,x] as input only changes the font but does not produce delta x^2/delta x. The deltas should be in Greek letters. If you followup with convert to TraditionalForm it will then show what I want.

Comment: So, you're question really has nothing to do with the removal of the TraditionalForm preferences setting in M11? As far as I know, using Shift-Enter never reformatted the input in previous versions either. It is possible to do this by messing around with the style sheet.

Comment: Carl, I'm amazed because I did not enter the title as written. I honestly have no idea where the shift enter part came from! I must have done something to cause it to appear, but it was not intentional ! Carl, my question was simply: can one set up a notebook to automatically render the input and output in Traditional Form. I do apologize for the confusion.

Comment: I would like to add that I attempted to solve this myself using the Options Editor as described above. I found that I could change the cell to Traditional Form in the editor for both Input and Output. To my surprise the Output changed as expected but the Input only changes the font. In order to get the Traditional Form I wanted I had to use the convert command. I am hoping that an experienced user can tell me how to get the TraditionalForm automatically after typing the expression and hitting enter.